# AngularJS: Clean up timeout right after callback was called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

So, I'd say it is good practice to clean up whenever I use $timeout or $interval in angularJS. I saw this [blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2548-don-t-forget-to-cancel-timeout-timers-in-your-destroy-events-in-angularjs.htm) talked about how you should clean it up (i.e. `$scope.$on("destroy" ... )`). My question is, is it ok to clean it up right after callback was executed? I have a service that returns promise of timeout something like this:

```
service.foo = function(){

  var timeout = $timeout(function(){
    // .. do something .. //
  }, 5000);

  return timeout;
};
```

so if I call this service, I did something like following:

```
var promise = myService.foo().then(function(){
  $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```

Is this reasonable approach if service foo is likely to be called multiple times in same view? Any advices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the timer was resolved already, then there is no difference if you clean it up or not. It's already past what the blog is warning about, which is timers being executed after scope was destroyed.

That said, as the blog suggests, it is a good practice to clean it up on `$destroy`, since you can never be 100% sure it will execute, users are unpredictable. The performance won't be impacted too much and you can sleep in peace, knowing the app won't perform any unneeded activities.

Answer (score 0):

cancel the timeout once its called.

```
var timeout = $timeout(function(){
    //cancel timeout
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: oh well that works too but what I asked was, is this good or reasonable practice to do it. I didn't ask where/how to clean it up

Comment: well we do always clean it up just after its executed. why to keep it there until your scope destroys.